# Kinetic.JS - why does layer order change overwrite my colour?

Tags: html, canvas, layer, kineticjs

I'm currently playing with Kinetic.JS. I have drawn a rather crude UFO-like shape in two parts, a hull (red) and a disc (grey).

**[Demo - JSBin](http://jsbin.com/osotil/2/edit)**

Question: **how come when I later arrange the shape ordering so the hull is above the disc, the disc bizarrely goes from grey to the hull's red?**

Uncomment the `moveToTop()` line at the bottom of my JSBin to see what I mean. Here's the pertinent (condensed) code.

```
//ship hull
var hull = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: function(ctx) {
        ctx.arc(game_dims.w / 2, game_dims.h * 0.6, game_dims.h * 0.45, 0, Math.PI, true);
        this.fill(ctx);
    },
    fill: 'red'
});

//ship disc
var disc = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: game_dims.w / 2,
    y: game_dims.h * 0.6,
    radius: {x: game_dims.w * 0.45, y: 30},
    fill: '#888'
});

//draw
layer.add(hull);
layer.add(disc);
stage.add(layer);

//post-production
hull.moveToTop(); // <-- weirdness - changes disc colour!?
layer.draw();
```

I am aware I could draw the two shapes in reverse order to get the desired order, but that is not what I want with this question - I'm interested in rearrangement of order after drawing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your draw function of the hull needs to tell the context it's drawing a new path:

```
function(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(...);
        this.fill(ctx);
}
```

By adding the `beginPath()` command you are telling the context that you are not in fact adding to the previous path, but drawing a new one instead. This is also what makes `this.fill()` fill the previous shape with red, because in your example the context is still referring to the disc when it attempts to fill it